# Magento Show Payment Method Validation

Tags: magento-1.9, payment-methods, ajax, payment-gateway, exception

I'm working on a magento 1.9 payment gateway extension.

It have a little form on payment method step and when we fill and clickon next button it validate

after validate it call to this function

```
/public_html/app/code/community/Shopworks/Billink/Model/Payment/Method.php


private function throwPaymentException($errorMessage)
    {
        //Because OSC does not show the errorMessage from the exception, we also store the error in the session. This
        //way we can collect it from the session and display it in the form.
        $_SESSION[self::VALIDATION_MESSAGE] = $errorMessage;

        //Throw the exception
        $errorMessageField = 'p_method_' . self::PAYMENT_METHOD_BILLINK_CODE;

             // Mage::throwException($errorMessage);
        throw new Mage_Payment_Exception($errorMessage, $errorMessageField);
    }
```

But problem is **when fields are not valid, checkout redirects to cart page**
(the error return from ajax is 503 error when call "Mage_Payment_Exception")

I tested by remove Exception handler code, then checkout load next step without shows any errors.

Payment class image
[image]

Anyone know how to show the errors which return by validator without redirects to cart page or go to next checkout step, Thank You

Comment: Is it redirect to a third-party system after validation?

Comment: @SohelRana no if validation success it shows last step of payment, but when have error and use Exception handler  it shows as a 503 error

Comment: Show your payment method class.

Comment: @SohelRana https://pasteboard.co/Id02uQK.png this have the validations

Comment: Can you update question?

Comment: @SohelRana i updated the question

Comment: No, add your method class